# Remove method in BST with 2 children, won't remove it predecessor

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I am trying to write a remove method for a BST. It works if there is 0 or 1 children. However, if there is 2 children the method copies the data from the predecessor (the rightmost left child) to the node-to-be-removed and then it is SUPPOSED to remove the predecessor. For some reason, the predecessor is still in the tree and doesn't get removed properly. I'm sure that this is a simple recursion bug, but I just can't figure it out! I would greatly appreciate any help, feedback and comments. Thank you.

```
    public boolean myRemove(Object o) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    E data = (E)o;
    root = myRemoveHelper(root, data);
    size--;
    return true;
}
private Node<E> myRemoveHelper(Node<E> root, E data) {
    if (root.data == data) {
        return myRemoveIt(root);
    }
    else if (data.compareTo(root.data) < 0) {
        root.left = myRemoveHelper(root.left, data);
    }
    else {
        root.right = myRemoveHelper(root.right, data);
    }
    return root;
}
private Node<E> myRemoveIt(Node<E> nodeToRemove) {
    if (nodeToRemove.left == null && nodeToRemove.right == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (nodeToRemove.left == null && nodeToRemove.right != null) {
        return nodeToRemove.right;
    }
    else if (nodeToRemove.left != null && nodeToRemove.right == null) {
        return nodeToRemove.left;
    }
    else {
        Node<E> temp = nodeToRemove.right;
        while (temp.left != null) {
            temp = temp.left;
        }
        nodeToRemove.data = temp.data;

        //does not remove the duplicate! :(
        nodeToRemove.left = myRemoveHelper(temp, temp.data);
        return nodeToRemove;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question you said you take the `the rightmost left child` **but** in the `myRemoveIt` you goes to `leftmost right child` in:

```
Node<E> temp = nodeToRemove.right;
while (temp.left != null) {
    temp = temp.left;
}
```

But after you assign to left: `nodeToRemove.left = myRemoveHelper(temp, temp.data);`.

You need to change that to:

```
nodeToRemove.right = myRemoveHelper(nodeToRemove.right, temp.data);
```

As now you sure the `temp.data` is on leaf (or at least we know he missing left side) and the new root you send to `myRemoveHelper` is the right side one as the new data is already been set.